# LinearHashTable iter not dereferencable and iter not

Tags: c++, visual-c++, poco-libraries

Hy all :)

I am using 1.5.4-all (2014-10-22) in my VC++ project (Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 18.00.21005.1 for x86 platform).

My problem is that I get the following error message after some time. The time, after which the error occurs differ quiet a lot - sometimes it happens after 30 secs and sometimes after 5 minutes. 
[image]

I could locate the source for the error in the LinearHashTable.h file at line 214:
[image]

I have the following method where a Shot (struct) is added to the table:

```
    void ShotSimulationService::SimulateShot(Shot shot) {
        MutexThreadLock.lock();
        shots.insert(ShotsSetType::ValueType(SimulationShot(shot)));
        errorCount = 0;
        MutexThreadLock.unlock();
    }
```

The call of SimulateShot is from another thread than the handling of the following code:

```
    void ShotSimulationService::Update(WebcamService* observable) {
        if (shots.empty()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            Mat frame = observable->GetLastImage().clone();
            ShotsSetType::Iterator iter = shots.begin();
            vector<Shot> deleteShots;
            errorCount++;
            while (iter != shots.end()){

                if (iter->SimulateStartExplosion()) {
                    //simulate gun explosion
                    OverlayImage(frame, gunShotImg, iter->startPoint);
                }

                //simulate explosion
                SimulationShot::SimulationHitStatus status = iter->status;
                if (status == SimulationShot::SimulationHitStatus::UNKNOWN) {
                    if (detectionService.HasShotHitPlayer(frame, *iter)) {
                        iter->status = SimulationShot::HIT_PLAYER;
                        iter->SetCurrentPointAsEndoint();

                        //Notify that player was hit
                        playerHitQueue.enqueueNotification(new PlayerHitNotification(iter->hitPlayer));
                    }
                }

                if (iter->SimulateEndExplosion()) {
                    if (status == SimulationShot::HIT_PLAYER) {
                        int explosionx = iter->endPoint.x - robotExplosionHalfXSize > 0 ? iter->endPoint.x - robotExplosionHalfXSize : 0;
                        int explosionY = iter->endPoint.y - robotExplosionHalfYSize > 0 ? iter->endPoint.y - robotExplosionHalfYSize : 0;
                        OverlayImage(frame, robotExplosionImg, Point2i(explosionx, explosionY));
                    }
                    else {
                        // status == SimulationShot::HIT_WALL or UNKNOWN
                        int explosionx = iter->endPoint.x - wallExplosionHalfXSize > 0 ? iter->endPoint.x - wallExplosionHalfXSize : 0;
                        int explosionY = iter->endPoint.y - wallExplosionHalfYSize > 0 ? iter->endPoint.y - wallExplosionHalfYSize : 0;
                        OverlayImage(frame, robotExplosionImg, Point2i(explosionx, explosionY));

                        if (status != SimulationShot::HIT_WALL) {
                            iter->status = SimulationShot::HIT_WALL;
                        }
                    }

                    if (iter->IsSimulationFinished()) {
                        deleteShots.push_back(*iter);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //simulate bullet
                    OverlayImage(frame, cheeseImg, iter->GetNextShotPoint());
                }

                ++iter;
            }

            //delete finished simulations
            MutexThreadLock.lock();
            for each (Shot shot in deleteShots)
            {
                shots.erase(shot);
            }
            MutexThreadLock.unlock();
        }
        catch (cv::Exception& e) {
            Logger& logger = Logger::get("Test");
            logger.error(e.what());
        }
    }
```

The Update method is called quiet often - always when a new webcam frame is available.

The callstack of the error starts in the following line:

```
    if (iter->SimulateEndExplosion()) {
```

In the method SimulateEndExplosion only members of the struct were used:

```
        bool SimulateEndExplosion() {
            if (status == HIT_PLAYER) {
                currPercentage = 1.0;
                return true;
            }

            if (currPercentage < 1.0) {
                return false;
            }

            ++endExplosionCtr;
            return endExplosionCtr <= maxEndExplosions;
        }
```

Does anybody have an idea why this problem occurs?

Any help and any feedback is welcome!! I have absolutly no idea what is going wrong here :(

Thanks!

Comment: You don't lock the mutex while iterating so that the other thead can be inserting while you're iterating. That could invalidate existing iterators, even mid-loop.  Not sure if thats the issue but its worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating in one thread and inserting in another without protecting the operations with mutex in both threads will cause this problem; when you insert, iterator will be invalidated and you will get the assertion failure. You should protect both insertion and iteration with mutex.

Also, the way you are using mutex is not safe because mutex will not be unlocked if an exception is thrown between lock() and unlock(). Use ScopedLock instead and RAII will do the job automatically and safely in all cases:

```
void ShotSimulationService::SimulateShot(Shot shot) {
        Mutex::ScopedLock lock(MutexThreadLock);
        shots.insert(ShotsSetType::ValueType(SimulationShot(shot)));
        errorCount = 0;
        // unlock will be called by ScopedLock destructor
    }
```