# visual studio has triggered a breakpoint Poco NotificationCenter

Tags: c++, visual-c++, poco-libraries

I have the problem that I get the message "VS has triggered a breakpoint" and when I break there, VS jumps into the source code of POCO NotificationCenter:
[image]

I am using Poco 1.5.4.

The previous entry in the callstack is located in the following piece of code:

```
void WebSocketController::HandleReceivedMessages() {
    AutoPtr<Notification> notification(receivedMessagesQueue.waitDequeueNotification());

    while (!messageHandlerActivity.isStopped() && notification) {
        MessageNotification* messageNotification = dynamic_cast<MessageNotification*>(notification.get());
        if (messageNotification)
        {
            notificationCenter.postNotification(messageNotification);
        }

        notification = receivedMessagesQueue.waitDequeueNotification();
    }
}
```

The concrete line I can see in the callstack (with line number) is the following one:

```
notification = receivedMessagesQueue.waitDequeueNotification();
```

This is the code of the MessageNotification.h:

```
    class MessageNotification : public Notification
    {
    public:
        MessageNotification(Message *data);
        ~MessageNotification();
        Message* GetData();
    private:
        Message *data;
    };
```

This is the code of the MessageNotification.cpp:

```
    MessageNotification::MessageNotification(Message *data) {
        this->data = data;
    }

    MessageNotification::~MessageNotification() {
        delete data;
        data = nullptr;
    }

    Message* MessageNotification::GetData() {
        return data;
    }
```

And here you can see the constructors of the Message class:

```
        Message::Message(const MessageCommandEnum cmd, const string& to, StringMap *params, const string& data)
            : cmd(cmd), to(to), data(data) {
            this->params = params == nullptr ? new StringMap() : params;
        }

        Message::Message(const Message& msg) : to(msg.to), cmd(msg.cmd), data(msg.data) {
            params = new StringMap(*msg.params);
        }

        Message::Message(const Message* msg) : to(msg->to), cmd(msg->cmd), data(msg->data) {
            params = new StringMap(*msg->params);
        }

        Message::~Message() {
            if (params != nullptr) {
                delete params;
                params = nullptr;
            }
        }
```

The rest of the methods in this class are only getters/setters.

Any idea why this happens?

My researches told me, that this message occurs if the heap gets destroyed. But I cannot find any line of code where this should happen. 
The behavior is a little bit strange since when I press continue on the message, the applications runs without any problems. I do not have any problem when the application is not started with a debugger in the background (e.g. start the exe in the Debug folder).

I am still learning C++, so I  really appreciate any feedback/help.

Thanks

Comment: Since it happens on an `ObserverList` copy construction, and since `ObserverList` is a typedef for a `std::vector` of smart pointers (that should be pretty safe), I suspect heap smashing. That means that you wrote beyond the boundaries of another object on the heap that just happened to lie directly before the smashed object in memory (do you work with any objects that hold a local buffer? `char[]`, perhaps?) or through an invalid pointer that just happened to point to the unlucky object. Using something after it was deleted is a good way to get that. Of course, this is all guesswork.

Comment: Get Microsoft Application Verifier and enable heap check to see if you corrupt something obvious.

Comment: I could not figure out any problems with Microsoft Application Verifier - the log always mentions zero errors and zero warnings.

Comment: And no - there are no local buffers - I am afraid. But it is clear that the problem has something to do with the line "notification = receivedMessagesQueue.waitDequeueNotification();" After a reboot I do not get the described exception by VS anymore. Now I get a write access violation with the address of the notification variable everytime a new notification is available. That does not make sense to me?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoPtr notification in WebSocketController::HandleReceivedMessages() will be deleted by AutoPtr as soon as you assign another pointer to it. However, at that point, the pointer was passed to the NotificationCenter in another AutoPtr and wherever you try to dereference (or AutoPtr tries to delete) it later, it will cause undefined behavior.

Once you put the notification pointer in AutoPtr, just pass it on as AutoPtr (cast it with notification.cast<MessageNotification>()). <del>Also, MessageNotification constructor pointer argument is never passed in because you never construct a MessageNotification object (you just dynamically cast the Notification* to MessageNotification*).</del>

Look at the [NotificationQueue example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/samples/NotificationQueue/src/NotificationQueue.cpp) to understand how to do this the proper way.

Comment: Hello Alex! Thanks for your help - I will try it immediately. Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK, looking at my comment about MessageNotification constructor argument, I figured you probably do pass it in somewhere else, so you can disregard it. As a rule of thumb - never mix AutoPtr with naked pointers. If you absolutely must assign AutoPtr to a pointer, make sure you call duplicate()/release() manually (i.e. never call delete on a pointer that was wrapped in AutoPtr at any point).

Comment: And, looking at the code, it seems that you are using manual lock()/unlock(), which is not safe. Use ScopedLock as recommended in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27851837/linearhashtable-iter-not-dereferencable-and-iter-not). BTW, can you accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: No - there are no manual locks. Offtopic: everywhere I need to synchronize something I use ScopedLock (as you have showed me). The MessageNotification is created somewhere else (queue.enqueueNotification(new MessageNotification(message)); - message is a pointer). I have adapted my code to the NotificationQueue example and I use now notification.cast instead of dynamic_cast. I have also cleanup my code to make sure I don't run into a problem caused by mixing up AutoPtr and naked pointers. The code is running now without any excepations. Really great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I have also added ScopeLocks where I access the data of the notification as it is shown in the NotificationQueue example.

Comment: Maybe the documentation [here](http://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf) on slide 28 should be updated according to the NotificationQueue example.

Comment: You are right, I have opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/678). Thank you.